# Can I send the return value ostringstream.str() to the another ostringstream

Tags: c++, gdb

Can I return the oss.str() from a function and send that return value to another ostringstream?

like this,

```
std::string funcOne() 
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "time";
    return oss.str();
}

//...
//in another function,

std::string funcTwo() {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << funcOne();
    return oss.str();
}

//...
DEBUG("%s", funcTwo().c_str());
```

Edit: why I am asking this ?

I am getting a crash at oss.str() in funcOne()

```
#0  0x00007fd7a5a53f67 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fd7a5a5533a in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007fd7a63b1919 in std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x0000000000000005 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007fd7717f8730 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007fd7717f872f in ?? ()
#6  0x00007fd7a6656660 in vtable for std::ios_base::failure () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x00007fd7a5a92e7e in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#8  0x00007fd7a5a98646 in malloc_printerr () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#9  0x00007fd7a5a9ab45 in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#10 0x00007fd7a5a9c3d0 in malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#11 0x00007fd7a6373598 in operator new(unsigned long) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#12 0x00007fd7a63b1919 in std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#13 0x00007fd7a63b1c92 in std::string::_M_mutate(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#14 0x00007fd7a63b22ee in std::string::_M_replace_safe(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#15 0x00007fd7a63b33bf in std::string::replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#16 0x00007fd7a63ac328 in std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::str() const ()
   from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```

Also I have seen some cases saying that, oss.str () returns temporary object on which one can not do further operations as it will get destroyed after str() calling.

Comment: The "return value" is a `std::string`. It doesn't matter where it came from.

Comment: Why do you ask? Do you get an error? Doesn't it work as expected?

Comment: `funcTwo.c_str()` ==> `funcTwo().c_str()`

Comment: Please clarify your question. You did not indicate that you get any error or unexpected behavior. Are you asking whether there is undefined behavior? You also tagged `gdb` which seems to indicate that you have a specific problem while debugging? There is no other indication to that in the question though.

Comment: crash is seen at oss.str() in  funcOne()

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Is `DEBUG` a macro?  If so my guess would be that its expansion results in code that hangs on to and uses the pointer returned by `funcTwo().c_str()` *after* the `std::string` returned by `funcTwo()` has gone out of scope.  Just guessing without a [mcve] though.

Comment: @BharathiPathivada Is it crashing when you call only funcTwo().c_str(); without DEBUG?

Comment: Actually , this is not reproducible at my environment but on other environment.
If the crash is seen at DEBUG(), back trace  would have been pointed at some internal calls of DEBUG. No ?

Comment: @BharathiPathivada Not necessarily.  If the code exhibits [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) then it can crash anywhere -- or nowhere.  Showing the definition of `DEBUG` might prove useful.

Comment: @BharathiPathivada Actually i can say that returning ostringstream.str() from a function as you asked will not cause any crash. It has to be something else.

Comment: Thank you. I am thinking why the crash is seen at ostringstream then.

Answer (score 0):

You have a crash inside `malloc` implementation.

In 99.9999% of instances of such crash, the problem is heap corruption, and is often completely unrelated to the code that crashes.

Examples of heap corruption: deleting unallocated memory, deleting some memory twice, overflowing heap-allocated buffer, etc. etc.

Use [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) or [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org) to find the source of heap corruption quickly.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification